# How to automate choosing a file when file explorer pops up from a browser

Tags: python, selenium, subprocess

I'm trying to create a whatsapp script, its only that I'm stuck in the part where when my script clicks on the Photo Attachments, a file explorer would pop up to choose the picture, how is it possible to automate the choosing of files in it?[image: The file explorer im talking baout], i tried a few things with subprocess and os libraries but i didnt get anywhere with that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import subprocess
```

Those are the libraries im using right now.
Any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far. The question is not clear to me, where do you want to click on? Is it a folder in your computer? Where does selenium play a role where?

Comment: For Selenium you would avoid opening the browse prompt.  You can send keys to the <input type="file"> tag and submit the form.  There are times when you may need to generate some events in order for the <input> element to appear and/or submit the form, but in general you'd target that element and use sendkeys method to send the local file's path.  Then use the .submit() convenience function on it (or any form field).